# Erlang/OTP R13B ARM binary download

Tags: erlang, arm

Is there a site where Erlang/OTP binaries for ARM-Linux can be downloaded? www.erlang.org only has source release (and I haven't managed to cross-compile it on the initial attempts), while http://cean.process-one.net/downloads/ only has R12B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the website http://www.erlang-embedded.com/.

Comment: That seems to be the best available answer, though I'd prefer to use the Linux distribution which comes installed on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Is your board big enough to just build it on-board from source?  A beagleboard-xm will build Erlang in about 25min on a USB hard drive.  I used a gentoo arm stage3 chroot and built erlang using "emerge erlang".

I've done enough cross-compiling to know to avoid it.  ARM CPUs are fast enough now that I can dispense with it.